# Lucene : How to give more importance to certain documents ?

Tags: lucene, couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I am using couchdb-lucene in my web application. I have a feature where I search for users.

Each user is a document with properties such as "Fullname", "Username" and "Activity".

Activity is just a float value that indicates how active that user is. So I want lucene to consider this factor as well while giving a score to each of the users. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While indexing, you may use the `Document.setBoost()` method. Also, you can do this not only on the Document level, it's also possible for one field of a Document by calling `Field.setBoost()`.

Comment: You could also boost at query time. Query q = ...; q.setBoost(..);

Comment: still confused about this being accepted as the answer. You cannot call 'Document.setBoost()' in couchdb-lucene. You have to add {"boost":boost_value} when you add the field. If this question is really about Lucene itself, then please change the description.

Answer (score 0):

You can boost things that you add to the Document as described at https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/blob/master/README.md (search for "boost").

Comment: Why this answer and the one from @BloodySmartie have been downvoted?

Comment: Because that answer refers to lucene and not couchdb-lucene.